# Why is my dropdown accordion not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get a simple dropdown accordion to work but not sure why it's not dropping down when clicked. Would like to get the 'Collapse all' button to switch to 'Open' when toggled (but not absolutely necessary). Open to the idea of a pure css accordion as well. Pretty new to javascript and JQuery so any info is helpful on this. TIA.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="chapters___2NT4M js-chapters">
        <section id="table-of-contents" class="table_of_contents___2HR-W accordion">
            <header class="table_of_contents__chapter_title___2W8SV">
                <h2 class="table_of_contents__chapter_heading___19HQO" tabindex="0">Navigate to..</h2>
                <button class="table_of_contents__toggle_all___fVHqW accordion-header" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" aria-haspopup="true">Collapse all</button>
            </header>
            <div class="accordion-content">
            <ul class="table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a" data-gtm-element="review_toc_list">
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#zener-diodes" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Zener Diodes</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#bridge-rectifiers" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Bridge Rectifiers</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#schottky-barrier-rectifiers" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Schottky Barrier Rectifiers</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#super-fast-recovery-rectifiers" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Super Fast Recovery Rectifiers</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#medium-power-bipolar-transistors" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Medium Power Bipolar Transistors</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#transient-protection" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Transient Protection</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#thyristor-modules" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">thyristor Modules</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#obsoleted-eol-products" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Obsoleted/EOL Products</a></li>
                <li class="table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf"><a href="#cross-reference" data-gtm-element="review_toc_link">Cross Reference</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.accordion-content {
    display: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDE0E7;
    background: #F6F7F9;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    color: #4a5666;
}

.accordion-header::before {
    content: '';
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: .75rem;
    height: .75rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #B1B5BE;
    margin-right: .75rem;
}

.accordion-content.active {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 80em) {
.chapters___2NT4M {
max-width: 570px;
}
}

.chapters___2NT4M {
clear: both;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
.table_of_contents___2HR-W {
margin: 2em 0 0;
}
}

.table_of_contents___2HR-W {
border-top: 3px solid #000;
margin: 5em 0 0;
padding-top: 0;
}

article, aside, footer, header, nav, section {
display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
.table_of_contents__chapter_title___2W8SV {
padding: 0;
}
}

.table_of_contents__chapter_title___2W8SV {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
font-size: 1.5rem;
line-height: 1.5rem;
padding: .4em 0 1.2em;
}

@media (min-width: 80em) {
.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a {
margin-bottom: 57px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a {
display: block;
}
}

.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a {
display: ;
margin: 0 0 52px;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
border-top: 0;
}

ol, ul {
margin: 0 0 1em 1.2em;
padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a .table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf {
font-size: 1.125rem;
line-height: 1.25rem;
}
}

.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a .table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf {
font-size: 1.1875rem;
line-height: 1.4375rem;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
margin-bottom: .8em;
}


.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a .table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf a, .d235 a {
color: #000;
}

.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a .table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf a {
color: #222;
text-decoration: none;
}

.table_of_contents__chapter_list___2gu-a  .table_of_contents__chapter_list_heading___3_laf a:hover {
color: #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready();
$(".accordion").on("click", ".accordion-header", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: do you correctly include jquery or bootstrap.js library on your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar to an accordion without using javascript by using the html element `details`.

```
<details>
    <summary>Title</summary>
    Some text
</details>
```

Then, when you click on the title, it expands itself. No js required

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here but I would start with the JS. Important thing here is that inside your click function `this` will be reference to the element that was clicked. So as I am reading it, you are toggling an active class on the button itself.

Also, I believe you intended to use `document.ready()` as the context of running the accordion code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion").on("click", ".accordion-header", function() {
    $(".accordion-content").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

I have not got any sliding in this snippet but hopefully this gets your click connected to the CSS change that shows/hides the accordion content.